# All of my Scripts and Enques are getting file not found

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, headers, wp-enqueue-style

I have the following script and enque function, and the site properly renders it in the html head, however when I click the link to the css and javascript files the i get a url not found, however the url is correct. I changed the permissions to 777 for all the folders so I am not sure why it cant see it. You can view the error site [here](http://update.mrskitson.ca/) and the error [here](http://update.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/themes/mrskitson.caVersion?#3/library/css/style.css).

```
// loading modernizr and jquery, and reply script
function bones_scripts_and_styles() {
  if (!is_admin()) {

    // modernizr (without media query polyfill)
    wp_register_script( 'bones-modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/libs/modernizr.custom.min.js', array(), '2.5.3', false );

    // register main stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'bones-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css', array(), '', 'all' );

    // ie-only style sheet
    wp_register_style( 'bones-ie-only', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/ie.css', array(), '' );

    // comment reply script for threaded comments
    if ( is_singular() AND comments_open() AND (get_option('thread_comments') == 1)) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    //adding scripts file in the footer
    wp_register_script( 'bones-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

    // enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bones-modernizr' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bones-stylesheet' );
    wp_enqueue_style('bones-ie-only');
    /*
    I recommend using a plugin to call jQuery
    using the google cdn. That way it stays cached
    and your site will load faster.
    */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bones-js' );

  }
}
```

Comment: Give your theme a more friendly url, preferably one without dots or hash signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called your theme `mrskitson.caVersion#3`. Do you know what a hash symbol (`#`) does in a URL? So, browsers are trying to load the script here:

`http://update.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/themes/mrskitson.caVersion`

And then jump down to an element with ID matching everything after the #.

Change the name of the theme folder!

Answer (score 0):

Your theme directory contains some unusual characters. Theme directory names should only consist of lowercase letters, dashes and numbers.